# Styling an HTML form select box

Tags: html, css, forms, select

I am styling an HTML form select box to match the style of the whole form element. The form is designed with big text set in 36 px, so the selected value of the select box needs to be in 36 px also.

In Safari, the selected value shows in 36 px, which is good, and when I open the select box to choose a value, the choices stay the small, default Safari font. This is what I would like to happen on every browser. However, in Chrome and Firefox, the select box opened font size takes the one from the select box, resulting in a very oversized and unusable select box.

I am wondering if there is a way to style a select box closed and opened states differently.

Comment: Can you show what you have until now? possibly add it to jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you share the html and css

Comment: I think it'll be easier to show it directly. The website is in french. There are two select fields in the page, Canada and Alberta.

http://brunobryan.com/dev/bnlmtl/infolettre/

Comment: Bruno, the issue with showing it directly is that questions should be self-contained so that they will be useful to other people in the future. Once that external resource changes, it devalues your question.

Comment: Ok, I thought it'd be easier to understand that way, but I understand the principle. I created a jsFiddle with it.

Comment: Here's the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/y4qeG/

Comment: I've spent a fair amount of time trying to get an option to do anything other than inherit the select's font style, in chrome, and not found a way to do it.

Comment: I took out the #mc_embed_signup from the CSS and it styles fine in IE and Chrome.